# How to get all classes with specified selector from HTML text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have AJAX code that return me HTML that need to render:

```
success: function (html) {
```

Here `html` is:

```
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
<div class="item">...</div>
```

I need to render it one by one so need to extract them but something doesn't work.
I don't get `<div class="item">...</div>` I just get `[Object object]`:

```
success: function (html) {
                var ctrls = [];
                $(html).each(function (index, value) {
                    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'item') {                        
                        ctrls.push(value);
                ...
```

I have never used `.each` before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to find the elements that match your class selector THEN iterate over them.  According to your comments, it seems like your elements are really inside a container so `find` is the operation you want. If you actually had a collection of operations `filter` would be the correct choice.

```
$(html).find('.item').each(function() {
   ctrls.push(this);
});
```

Note, if you want the text (HTML) of the matched elements, use

```
$(html).find('.item').each(function() {
   ctrls.push($(this).html());
});
```

Generally, though, when manipulating DOM elements, it's better to store the actual elements rather than their text values.  This is especially true if you're going to attach handlers directly to them as the attachment of the handlers would be lost if you convert to HTML in order to manipulate them.

Comment: This is same as `$('.item,#foo,#bar').find('.item')` But what op needs is `$('.item,#foo,#bar').filter('.item')` Am I right..?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I'm assuming that `html` is actually an html response via AJAX not a collection of elements. `Find` is the right operation here.

Comment: @tvanfosson I get [object HTMLDivElement] when try to alert(this).

Comment: @1110 of course, it's a DOM element. What do you want? The text?

Comment: But `$('<div class="item"></div><div class="item"></div>').find('.item').length` will be `0` Right..? Can you clarify me on this.?

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy you're right, but it seems like they're actually in a container according to the previous comment

Comment: @tvanfosson Thanks for your patience in clarifying my doubts.! +1

Comment: @tvanfosson Yes, I need to get element like `<div class="item"><h2></h2><a href="#"</a></div>` how can I get that value from this object?

Comment: @1110 - you say element, but do you really mean that you want text?  You can do that by changing `ctrl.push(this);` to `ctrl.push($(this).html());`